# Link Products to user ID

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I am using asp.net identity and I have a class called Products but what I want to be able to do is link products to the user, how would I go about adding in a column that would store the active loged in user of identity against the product. By the way I am mostly using scaffolding to produce my cruds so would want a way comp table with this.

Obv I am using identity core and just need to no how to add the correct field to get it store the user Id.

What I also need to happen is anyone who is in Administrator group then it would show all the products but when its a user it would only show the ones created by them?

```
public class Products
{
    [Key]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    public string ShotDescription { get; set; }

    public decimal OldPrice { get; set; }

    public decimal NewPrice { get; set; }

    public bool DisableBuyButton { get; set; }

    public bool DisableWishListButton { get; set; }

    public bool ShowForPrice { get; set; }


    public bool NotReturnable { get; set; }

    public int MinimumCartQty { get; set; }

    public int MaximumCartQty { get; set; }

    public string SKU { get; set; }


    public bool ShippingEnabled { get; set; }

    public decimal Weight { get; set; }

    public decimal Length { get; set; }

    public decimal Width { get; set; }

    public decimal Height { get; set; }

    public string Categories { get; set; }

    public string ManufacturerPartNumber        { get; set; }

    public DateTime AvailableDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime AvailableEndDate { get; set; }

    public string AdminComment { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

    public DateTime UpdatedOn { get; set; }


    public Boolean DisplayAvailability { get; set; }

    public DateTime ExpectedDateBackOnStock { get; set; }

    public bool IsOnBackOrder { get; set; }

    public int Warehouse { get; set; }

    public int BinNumber { get; set; }

    public int IlseNumber { get; set; }



    public bool IsGiftCard { get; set; }

    public bool IsDownloadableProduct { get; set; }

    public bool IsRental { get; set; }


    public string SeoDescription { get; set; }


    public int   Stock { get; set; }

    public int PropertyImageId { get; set; }





}
```

Comment: Each product has only one userid or many?

Comment: @ecKO its to allow the program to filter based on the current user to a user can have multiple products

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should create a User property within your person class, which stores the value (as well as a get and set).

Then you would need to call

```
    var user = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
```

in the class you're doing your logic, whilst storing this `user` variable into the User property you created in the Products class.

Comment: You did not even read the class properly its called products and I am wanting to store the user within that

Comment: I apologise for the mistake, then you would need to do `Products.properyName = user`. Or instead of saving it into a variable called user, just store it directly into the property.

Comment: It should do, considering what we're doing is just setting the property of the Entity. Let me know if it works.

Comment: What I am wanting is a solution that will tell the scaffoliding to then filter on the users somehow i dont think this will do it

Comment: Could you not set this on the model knowing that the user will have to log in with the [Authorise] tag on the page in quesiton ?.

Comment: Can i clarify, that for every single product that is stored, you will have the logged in user saved against it? And as long as the user is stored within the entity, then you should be able to access that value through the scaffolding, as it is now a stored value.

Comment: Yes then the scaffolding should filter that list but then I reliease I Will have to adjust the linq query for that

Comment: So you would like a list of users stored for each product, or a list of products stored for a single user? Yes but it should still not be a problem (if you store the logged-in user as a property in the products) - the scaffolding should still locate it.

Comment: Yeah so only that customer who signs in will only see the products that they have but if they are a member of the admin role they can see all the products

Comment: Yes, okay, then you would need to have the property in the Products class as a List and do the same thing i suggested, except .add to the list, and when you need to access that information to see what users are attached to the product, and then loop through them to access them? It would just need to be a property and it should work.